# Use QSPI or QUAD SPI as a "normal" SPI?

Tags: stm32, spi, high-speed

I need high speed SPI peripherals to control some SK9822 LED's (which can be clocked at up to 30 MHz, which I'd like to use (the speed is needed because of the LEDs being in motion)

So I searched for a MCU with 2 fast SPI's
I chose the STM32F446RE which does have 2 high speed SPI (SPI1 and SPI4), BUT SPI4 is not available on the LQFP64 package.

Now my problem is, that I control 2 "Stripes" of LED's and thus need 2x 30 MHz capable SPI interfaces. (or some interface with a clock and data pin, since the LED's only need clock and data, no MISO, only MOSI)

I searched for alternatives and found that there is a QSPI on the LQFP64 package, which would be fast enough (see page 130).[(Link to the datasheet of the MCU)](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f446re.pdf)

Now my question is, is it possible to use QSPI as a "normal" SPI with the speed of 30 MHz?
If so, how would I program it?
Is there anything special to do or something like that?

(I only know SPI, never worked with QSPI)

Thank you in advance for your replies!

Comment: There is an application note specifically for QSPI, including information on single-SPI Mode, see https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an4760-quadspi-interface-on-stm32-microcontrollers-and-microprocessors--stmicroelectronics.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Based on the datasheet, 30 MHz should not be a problem:

[image]

If you used the SPI, using the QSPI will not be a problem at all for you. You may need to prepare the bits to be able to control the LEDs correctly.

Comment: Okey, yea that's what I saw too, it's fast enough

but I have no idea on how I'd send the proper data / what the differences of QSPI vs SPI are if I use it only for a CLK and MOSI signal


But good to know that it should be possible, thank you for your answer! :)